# Convert a SQL database design to a drupal schema installation file

Tags: database

I have a, rather big, application that I would like to integrate into Drupal reusing the current database design / logic.

Is there a tool out there that can help me to build the PHP part of the hook_schema definition taking the current database model or an SQL file with the DB declaration as a starting point ?

From what I know it should be pretty trivial to convert a SQL file to a PHPish definition compatible with drupal.

The utility should convert SQL types to Drupal types and declare primary keys, unique keys and index ala drupal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I knew of a few possabilities, only 2 may work. I haven't tried:

[dbtng_migrator](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) - migrates a drupal db to different DBMS engines at will. no schema export support.

[Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) - module to move data into and out of drupal databases.

> The Data module provides
>
> an API for dynamically allocating tables for single-row records. an
>   API for insert/update/delete operations and describing how tables join
>   to each other. automatic views integration. **a way to export table
>   definitions to code.**

[Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) - `drush dl schema` Includes the following functionality not found in Core:

> Schema structure generation: the module examines the live database and
>   creates Schema API data structures for all tables that match the live
>   database.

I have a drupal DB with other database connections defined in `settings.php`. You can go into Schema settings and tell to look at any named database connection (by default drupal is `default`). Here I select `dew_remote_sources` -- a "remote" (non drupal) database of data. The `inspect` tab then lists the SchemaAPI `hook_schema` defintion for each table with dummy comments to fillin.
[image: switch schema to inspect a db connection]
[image: sample stubbed out schema defintion from sql structure]

Lastly [views_schema](http://drupal.org/project/views_schema) is pretty cool. It creates the hook_views_data for drupal tables based on their schema api definition.

Honestly I dont think you looked at @4Life answer close enough because given a db connection string, Schema does what you want.

Comment: Yes @tenken my fault, I made a wrong assumption. Schema is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: The Schema module did the trick for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the schema module.

The Schema API allows modules to declare their database tables in a structured array (similar to the Form API) and provides API functions for creating, dropping, and changing tables, columns, keys, and indexes.

http://drupal.org/project/schema

Comment: I already knew about this module, but what I want to achieve is quite different. I would like to convert my already designed database (for example from a sql script) to add the table definitions to drupal using hook_schema.

Comment: it helps to do some research into how to use the modules people suggest. if you have a _live_ instance of your DB from a mysql schema/dumpfile, then Schema can do this. dont just downvote blindly because you thnk you know everything a module does.

Comment: @4life that was a stupid downvote by me, if you edit your answer I will be able to remove it. Sorry about that.